# Will lithium-ion batteries be okay in off-season?

Tags: power-supply, power, lithium-ion, solar-cell

I have a cottage in Nova Scotia that is off-grid. I will need to replace my large Rolls wet cell batteries soon and am thinking replacing them with lithium ion batteries.

Will these batteries be okay still connected to my solar system but unattended for 4-5 months? They are in a basement that rarely falls below 0°C (32°F).

Comment: What do you mean by "rarely"? It takes just one event of extreme freeze to bring a battery out of thermal specs and potentially damage it forever. You should tell us the maximum and minimum temperature limits you can experience in your basement.

Comment: any specific reason for using Li-ion batteries as opposed to anything else?

Answer (score 6):

> Will these batteries be okay still connected to my solar system but unattended for 4-5 months

Possibly. It depends on how they are charged. If they are charged to the rated maximum voltage and held there all day, they will degrade over time. Li-ion cells do not like to be held at the max voltage.

Ideally, you charge them to 50 % to 70 %, and disconnect them.

If that is not possible, and they must remain connected to the solar charging, then see if you can reduce the top voltage.

For example, if they use LFP (LiFePO4) cells, holding them at 3.6 V / cell increases their series resistance rather rapidly and decreases their capacity, though not quite as rapidly. Instead, holding them at 3.4 V / cell does not degrade them as fast, and you only lose some 3 % of the capacity.

For LCO or NMC cells, try to charge them to no more than 3.9 V / cell.

Answer (score 4):

Reduce the state of charge to 40-50% and then unplug. They will be fine. Definitely don’t leave them there 100% charged. Not sure what kind of batteries you’re looking at but it is important that each individual cell is at an even voltage (each cell should be around 40-50 % charge.   The more expensive units should be able to be set to a specific charge and hold it there. Safer to unplug though in case something fails.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance they will be OK for 4-5 months. However, the batteries will probably have a longer life if they are periodically charged to about 75% of their capacity, and not allowed to drop below 50%. Charging them above 80% or especially above 90% actually reduces their lifespan. A battery management system (BMS) capable of such maintenance might be worthwhile.

Also, as your batteries are not mobile, and hence energy density might not be an issue for you, you might look into LiFePO4 battery chemistry as one of the possible LiIon chemistries.

Comment: LiFePO4 _is_ a Li-ion chemistry. It is one of the ~6 Li-ion chemistries : https://imgur.com/a/PPNeI

Comment: @DavideAndrea one can also find references where LiFePO4 is distinguished from Li-Ion. For example "Lithium Iron Phosphate Vs. Lithium-Ion: Differences and Advantages" https://blog.epectec.com/lithium-iron-phosphate-vs-lithium-ion-differences-and-advantages

Comment: Oh I know: I see plenty of sloppy terminology in the battery world. That's why I asked the Li-ion chemists, and they say: "A Li-ion cell is one that uses 'rocking chair' intercalation of Lithium ions in the two electrodes". LFP cells use rocking chair intercalation of Lithium ions in the two electrodes and are therefore Li-ion cells.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

**You need either a specialized BMS (Battery Management System) that can block charging at low temperatures or highly specialized cells that are very expensive.**

Charging Li-ION batteries below ~5°C is dangerous, and it can be done only with a system designed for it.
You really want an expert to design and build that system for you. You should consult companies that do that professionally, with adequate safeguards in place to avoid fires and property damage.

---

It all depends on how the batteries are connected to the solar systems. Most probably you would want to have a professionally designed storage system, that is designed with your environmental situation in mind (temperature excursions, humidity, salt in sea breeze, etc.).

In general any kind of battery can be discharged over a given temperature range that is wider than the temperature range suitable for charging it.
Lithium cells are no exception.

Discharging Li-ION the cells well below 0°C is possible (albeit you lose some capacity) without damaging the cell. However 0°C is the limit for *charging* them safely, at least common cells not designed for sub-zero charging.

Here is an excerpt from [Battery University](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-410-charging-at-high-and-low-temperatures)(emphasis mine):

> Batteries operate over a wide temperature range, but this does not give permission to also charge them at these conditions. **The charging process is more delicate than discharging and special care must be taken. Extreme cold and high heat reduce charge acceptance and the battery should be brought to a moderate temperature before charging.**
> [...]
>
> #### Low-temperature Charge
>
> [...]
> **Lithium Ion**: Li-ion can be fast charged from 5°C to 45°C (41 to 113°F). **Below 5°C, the charge current should be reduced, and *no charging is permitted at freezing temperatures*** because of the reduced diffusion rates on the anode. During charge, the internal cell resistance causes a slight temperature rise that compensates for some of the cold. The internal resistance of all batteries rises when cold, prolonging charge times noticeably. This also affects discharge performance noticeably with Li-ion.
>
> Many battery users are unaware that **consumer-grade lithium-ion batteries cannot be charged below 0°C (32°F)**. Although the pack appears to be charging normally, plating of metallic lithium occurs on the anode during a sub-freezing charge that leads to a **permanent degradation in performance and *safety***. Batteries with lithium plating are more vulnerable to failure if exposed to vibration or other stressful conditions. **Advanced chargers (Cadex) prevent charging Li-ion below freezing.**
>
> Advancements are being made to charge Li-ion below freezing temperatures. Charging is indeed possible with most lithium-ion cells but only at very low currents. According to research papers, the allowable charge rate at –30°C (–22°F) is 0.02C. At this low current, the charge time would stretch to over 50 hours, a time that is deemed impractical. **There are, however, specialty Li-ions that can charge down to –10°C (14°F) *at a reduced rate.***
>
> **Some Li-ion manufacturers offer custom-made cells for cold-charging.** Specialty chargers will also be needed that decrease the C-rate according to temperature and charge the battery to a lower voltage peak; 4.00V/cell rather than the customary 4.20V/cell for example. Such limitations decrease the energy a Li-ion battery can hold to roughly 80% instead of the customary 100%. Charge times will also be prolonged and can last 12 hours and longer when cold.
>
> **Li-ion batteries charging below 0°C (32°F) must undergo regulatory issue to certify that no lithium plating will occur**. In addition, a specially designed charger will keep the allotted current and voltage within a safe limit throughout the temperature bandwidth. **Certification of such batteries and chargers are very costly** that will reflect in the price. Similar regulatory requirements also apply to intrinsically safe batteries (See BU-304: Why Are Protection Circuits Needed?)
>
> There are cell and charger manufacturers claiming to charge Li-ion at low temperatures; however, most companies do not want to take the risk of potential failure and assume liability. Yes, Li-ion will charge at low temperature but research labs dissecting these batteries see concerning results.

BTW, you say that (emphasis mine):

> They are in a basement that **rarely** falls below 0°C (32°F).

The problem is that it takes **just one single time** the temperature falling below ~5°C and if your system tries to charge the batteries they can be damaged or they can even vent with fire, unless the charger system is designed to handle the event (either refusing to charge or charging with drastically reduced current).

---

### Further readings on the subject

https://dcbattery.tech/charging_your_lithium_battery_below_zero

https://www.aceongroup.com/news/why-does-low-temperature-affect-li-ion-batteries

https://www6.slac.stanford.edu/news/2021-08-26-how-extreme-cold-can-crack-lithium-ion-battery-materials-degrading-performance

https://www.continentalbattery.com/blog/how-does-cold-weather-affect-lithium-ion-batteries

Comment: "a specialized BMS (Battery Management System) that can block charging at low temperatures ". Not that specialized. I assure you that the BMS that comes with any of the Li-ion batteries OP is likely to buy does have a low temperature charging disable.

Comment: @DavideAndrea Well, it depends. "what the OP is likely to buy" is not clear from his question.  OP said ` I will need to replace [...] and am thinking replacing them with lithium [...]` So it's unclear whether he is an advanced hobbyist that will try to build his own system (lots of people doing this with PV panels out there nowadays) or if he will contact a company to do the job. FWIW, for the way the OP formulated their question they could even be a complete newbie trying to just exchange lead acid batteries with Li-ION cells! So I felt compelled to state what technology would be necessary.

Comment: @DavideAndrea BTW, shopping questions are off-topic here, so the OP question should be answered in the context of electronic design, otherwise the question shouldn't be answered at all (and the question be closed).